# SQL Trigger creating trouble

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, database

I have the movie executive table

> movieexec

with the columns

> (name varchar2(20), address varchar2(20), cert# number(10), networth float)

I want to create a trigger which calculates the average networth, and if it exceeds some amount say 400000 then further insertion should not be possible and a error message should be displayed.

I implemented the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pronet
AFTER INSERT
ON movieexec
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE netavg float;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(networth) INTO netavg FROM movieexec;
  IF(netavg>400000) THEN
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'average limit reached, cannot insert');
  ENDIF;
END
```

But the below error occurs

```
ERROR at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
  if
5. DECLARE netavg float;
6. BEGIN
7. **SELECT AVG(networth) INTO netavg FROM movieexec;**
8. IF(netavg>400000) THEN
9. RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'average limit reached, cannot insert');
```

kindly assist.

Comment: The line number in the error is referring to the PL/SQL block, not the overall trigger statement. So it's the final `end` it doesn't like, not the `select`. And that's because the previous line, `endif;`, is malformed - missing a space.

Comment: The trigger was created successfully, but the following error is occurring when i insert into movieexec..... ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.MOVIEEXEC is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. 
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PRONET", line 4 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.PRONET' – Gautham 2 mins ago edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create table as

```
CREATE TABLE movieexec
(
    name          VARCHAR2 (20),
    address   VARCHAR2 (20),
    cert_no   NUMBER (10),
    networth   FLOAT
);
```

and create trigger as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pronet
    AFTER INSERT
    ON movieexec
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    netavg  FLOAT;
BEGIN
    SELECT  AVG (networth)
      INTO  netavg
      FROM  movieexec;

    IF (netavg > 400000)
    THEN
        raise_application_error (-20000,
                                         'average limit reached, cannot insert'
                                        );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you creating this under SYSTEM user?

Comment: Yes i created it under the user, SYSTEM.
ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.MOVIEEXEC is mutating, trigger/function may not see it<br/>
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.PRONET", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.PRONET'

Comment: @Gautham You can avoid mutating error if you make BEFORE INSERT instead of AFTER INSERT, but I doubt that will not help your cause. See [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm) to avoid mutating triggers issues.

Comment: @Gautham And never create your objects under SYS, SYSTEM users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe way to do this with a trigger, as there will always be a way to subvert it.

In Oracle EE you might create a fast refresh on commit materialised view to store the aggregation, and place a check constraint on it.

Also, never use the SYS or SYSTEM accounts for creating your own objects.